# How can I torify my entire Arch Linux system?

Tags: iptables, tor

I use an Arch-based distro (Parabola GNU/Linux-libre), and I'd like to torify my whole system (I know the risks). I've read [the Tor wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tor#Transparent_Torification) from ArchWiki, but I'm unable to torify all my programs without running `torify` before. I did all of what appears there, enabling kernel modules, creating iptables rules, etc.

I use OpenRC btw.

Comment: I don't know much about Arch or Parabola, but my comment is about your question: you tell basically "the howto doesn't work". How to help without knowing what step went wrong, what measure you did to try and pinpoint where it's not working as expected?